# How to delete old DotA 2 item builds created before the guide system?

Tags: steam, dota-2, steam-cloud

With the patch from 20 February the new guide system is online which provides skill builds and item builds. I have been using the online tool to create those builds, but my old itembuilds saved in `\Steam\userdata\XXX\570\remote\itembuilds` are still there and cannot be deleted. Moreover when I want to pick one of my custom guides these item builds are still suggested. Is there any way to safely delete those?

Comment: To clarify, you're talking about a custom suggested item build right?

Comment: The item builds stored in the mentioned folder are the ones we could creates via the shop UI by drag and dropping items there. The new builds aka guides are special files which can be activated with [the new UI](http://media.steampowered.com/apps/dota2/images/posts/blog_builds_hud.jpg) however my old builds are displayed there, too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easy way to work around the Steam cloud sync for these files is not to delete them, but to make DotA2 ignore them. All you need to do is delete the contents, but leave the files.

Here are the needed steps:

1. Exit Steam
2. Go to your `\Steam\userdata\XXX\570\remote\itembuilds` directory
3. For each .txt file there, open the file in notepad, delete the contents and then save and close
4. Restart Steam
5. If the *Cloud Sync Conflict* dialog appears, just click *local files - upload to the steam cloud*

Now your ancient builds should no longer show up on the in-game UI!

Comment: on my machine the folder that holds the scratch guides is now `\guides` instead of `\itembuilds`

Answer (score 0):

Move the folder called "guides" to your desktop and then move it back when it prompts you with a sync error.

Comment: If you have something new to add, just edit your previous answer! There's no need to make another answer. :)

Comment: Also, could you summarize the link?  I know it's Steam, but we don't like the possibility of link rot.

Comment: The link is basically telling you how to delete data stored on steam cloud, in this case, you'd want to delete the old "draft" guides which you cannot delete in-game.